Error: "The user field is required" when posting data to ASP.NET Core Web API
I am developing a Vue.js application that communicates with an ASP.NET Core Web API for user data management. I am encountering an issue when trying to POST user data to the API, where I consistently get the following error message:

The user field is required

Vue3Js with axios:
Objective: my goal is to send user data from my Vue.js frontend to the ASP.NET Core Web API and have it successfully inserted into the database.
Error:

The user field is required

This suggests a validation error during the API request.
Steps taken:
I have checked the payload sent from Vue.js to the API, and it includes all necessary fields (first_Name, last_Name, email_Address, birthdate, role_id).
The date format (birthdate) in the payload matches the expected format (YYYY-MM-DD) for the SQL Server database.
I have reviewed the AddUser method in my API controller (UserController) to ensure correct model binding and validation logic.
Nullable fields such as role_id in my Users model are handled appropriately in the API controller.
I have inspected the transformed data before sending the POST request from Vue.js to confirm it matches the expected format.
Code snippets:
Vue.js PostUser method:
GetUser() {
        axios.get(API_URL + 'api/User')
            .then((response) => {
                this.User = response.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
            });
},
PostUser() {
    const usersToPost = this.User.map(user => {
        const { user_Id, ...userData } = user;

        // Format birthdate as YYYY-MM-DD
        const formattedDate = new Date(userData.birthdate);
        const birthdate = `${formattedDate.getFullYear()}-${('0' + (formattedDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${('0' + formattedDate.getDate()).slice(-2)}`;
        
        return {
            first_Name: userData.first_Name,
            last_Name: userData.last_Name,
            email_Address: userData.email_Address,
            birthdate: birthdate, // Use formatted birthdate
            role_id: userData.role_id
        };
    });

    axios.post(API_URL + 'api/User', usersToPost)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Users posted successfully:', response.data);
            // Handle response if needed (e.g., update UI, show success message)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error posting users:', error);
            // Handle error if needed (e.g., show error message)
        });
},mounted(){
    this.GetUser();
}

ASP.NET Core Web API AddUser method:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddUser(Users user)
{
    try
    {
        Users u = new Users();

        u.First_Name = user.First_Name;
        u.Last_Name = user.Last_Name;
        u.Email_Address = user.Email_Address;
        u.Birthdate = user.Birthdate;
        u.Role_id = user.Role_id;

        // Add logging to inspect the received user data
        Console.WriteLine("Received user data:");
        Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u));

        _fuentesContext.AddUser(u);

        return Ok(u);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error adding user:");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}

Users model class in ASP.NET Core:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AFuentes.API.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int User_Id { get; set; }
        public string? First_Name { get; set; }
        public string? Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string? Email_Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
        public int? Role_id { get; set; }
    }
}


The error can't come from the API unless you're returning that specific message in the response.  It doesn't look like you are.  The validation seems like it's on the frontend.  It's not a built-in feature, so what validation library are you using? How is it configured?  If it is somehow a backend error, set a breakpoint in the AddUser method, does it get hit?  Step through the debugger looking for exception. .NET errors should always appear somewhere in your logs, they don't just get silently passed back to frontend. We need this additional debugging information to answer the question.

Check that you are posting to the correct api endpoint. Your api controller code shows AddUser but your axios code shows 'api/User'.

Could you provide more debug details like console log, response messages and else. As I cannot reproduce your problem, according to my research it is more likely a vue issue.
